# WebRTC building for arm

Tags: linux, build, arm, webrtc

I want to build webrtc for my small machine with arm926ej-s processor.

After I install depot_tools, I did following steps:

```
gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
gclient sync --force
cd trunk
ninja -C out/Debug
```

All working fine and I can run some binary files, which I get after compiling.
Now, I want to compile for my arm machine. I do following:

```
rm -rf out
export GYP_CROSSCOMPILE=1
export GYP_DEFINES="target_arch=arm arm_float_abi=hard"
export CC=/path/to/my/gcc
export CXX=/path/to/my/g++
export AR=/path/to/my/ar
export CC_host=gcc 
export CXX_host=g++ 
gclient runhooks --force
```

Still all smoothly...
But when I try to compile it with command:

```
ninja -C out/Debug
```

I got many errors, like:

```
CC obj/chromium/src/third_par...p/srtp/crypto/cipher/libsrtp.aes_cbc.o
FAILED: /opt/virt2real-sdk/codesourcery/arm-2013.05/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -MMD -MF obj/chromium/src/third_party/libsrtp/srtp/crypto/cipher/libsrtp.aes_cbc.o.d -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_INT16_T -DHAVE_INT32_T -DHAVE_INT8_T -DHAVE_UINT16_T -DHAVE_UINT32_T -DHAVE_UINT64_T -DHAVE_UINT8_T -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -DINLINE=inline -DCPU_CISC -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=214024 -DTOOLKIT_VIEWS=1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_ASH=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_PRE_SYNC_BACKUP -DUSE_XI2_MT=2 -DENABLE_REMOTING=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DUSE_UDEV -DENABLE_EGLIMAGE=1 -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_GOOGLE_NOW=1 -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DCLD2_DATA_SOURCE=static -DENABLE_FULL_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_MANAGED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DUSE_NSS=1 -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWTF_USE_DYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1 -I../../chromium/src/third_party/libsrtp/config -I../../chromium/src/third_party/libsrtp/srtp/include -I../../chromium/src/third_party/libsrtp/srtp/crypto/include -Igen -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -pthread -fno-exceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -Wno-reserved-user-defined-literal -Xclang -load -Xclang /home/footniko/my/webrtcnative/trunk/tools/clang/scripts/../../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -fcolor-diagnostics -Wheader-hygiene -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wstring-conversion -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-format -Wno-unused-result -target arm-linux-gnueabihf -march=armv7-a -no-integrated-as -mtune=generic-armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb --sysroot=/home/footniko/my/webrtcnative/trunk/arm-sysroot -O0 -g -funwind-tables -Wno-undefined-bool-conversion -Wno-tautological-undefined-compare   -c ../../chromium/src/third_party/libsrtp/srtp/crypto/cipher/aes_cbc.c -o obj/chromium/src/third_party/libsrtp/srtp/crypto/cipher/libsrtp.aes_cbc.o
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Xclang'
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Xclang'
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Xclang'
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-add-plugin'
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Xclang'
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: find-bad-constructs: No such file or directory
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fcolor-diagnostics'
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wheader-hygiene'
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wstring-conversion'
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-target'
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: arm-linux-gnueabihf: No such file or directory
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-no-integrated-as'
```

Comment: need GYP_DEFINES="OS=android" ?

Comment: I'm not building for android.

Comment: I thought so, but I think OS=android will signify that this is cross-compiling and targeting mobile CPUs.

Comment: @9dan, No, it crashes when I made `gclient runhooks --force`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i also got this problem but it was because of the exports related to compiler choices (CC, CXX, etc.). Indeed this makes you faulty since -Xclang is not recognized by gcc.

Here is a method i used to try to compile. However, it seems that webrtc trunk is moving fast and it is no more working these last days. The biggest change that is related to your problem and the suggestion of 9dan : you need to say that you want to target android (and linux) and for this you need android_tools. But now, it is not fetched from webrtc, you should get the one from chromium.

Here is a summary of the install process.

## System requirements:

Prefer a virtualized Lubuntu14.04 64bit on at least 30Gb virtual drive space and 8GbRAM :

```
_Lubuntu is fast to use when virtualized and it is based on ubuntu which is necessary since installation scripts rely on ubuntu software packages names
_64bit is necessary since scripts like install-build-deps.sh expect 64bit system and install specific 32bit libraries
_30Gb at least because standard (non cross compiling) webrtc requires at least 10Gb but when adding all cross compiling stuff, drive space explodes !
_8GbRAM to be able to compile and link everything
```

Then, from this host, here is the install process:

## basic preliminary setup... supposing that no variables discussed later have already been exported

First install the essential packages to be able to fetch data and play with java :

```
// ensure all required depot are ready
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
// install most essential packages prior to fetching
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk git subversion
```

## initial Webrtc fetch

Create a directory to fetch and go

```
mkdir WebRTC
cd WebRTC
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH=<location of depot_tools>:"$PATH" // example : export PATH=/home/testing/WebRTC/depot_tools:"$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME=<location of Java SE 6 - JDK>  // example : export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk 
gclient sync --force
```

Note 0: sometime it fails saying gcc, pkg-config, etc have not been found. This often occurs on a fresh install where plenty of packages are missing.
Fortunately a script should have already been downloaded :

```
trunk/built/install-build-deps.sh
```

Run it to install all required packages  and rerun

```
gclient sync --force
```

## add all necessary android sdk&ndk that are required to target arm systems

```
echo "target_os = ['android', 'unix']" >> .gclient
gclient sync
cd trunk
source ./build/android/envsetup.sh
export GYP_DEFINES="$GYP_DEFINES OS=android"
gclient runhooks
```

Note 1: the android tools are no more directly available with webrtc. It is recommended to use the one from chromium.
then, in Webrtc folder or another one (example, the original location : trunk/third_party/).

```
cd myTargetDirectory // example cd trunk/third_party/
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools
```

Once android_tools are fetched, configure project to see it. Edit :

```
trunk/chromium/src/third_party/openmax_dl/dl/dl.gyp
```

and add the required variable android_ndk_root by adding the following line in the 'variables'  section at the beginning of the file:

```
'android_ndk_root':'<WebRTCfolder>/trunk/third_party/android_tools/ndk/',
example   'android_ndk_root':'/home/testing/WebRTC/trunk/third_party/android_tools/ndk/',
```

you can also export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT in your .bashrc

```
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=<WebRTCfolder>/trunk/third_party/android_tools/ndk/
example export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/testing/WebRTC/trunk/third_party/android_tools/ndk/
```

## prepare cross compile for armv7a based platform

```
// install all necessary packages
cd trunk
./build/install-build-deps.sh --arm
./build/install-build-deps-android.sh
```

/* => after different experiment, i used the above command, but i guess it is not absolutely necessary from a very clean install. Anycase, if done, command "./build/install-build-deps.sh --arm" should be used after in order to exchange some cross compiler packages
(mainly in order to keep g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf and gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf installed)
*/

```
./build/linux/install-arm-sysroot.py
export GYP_CROSSCOMPILE=1 /* => i used it but i ask myself if it is still necessary since an automatic declaration is performed later on.*/

export GYP_DEFINES="OS=linux target_arch=arm arm_version=7 arm_use_neon=1"
// other options like  arm_fpu=vfpv3-d16 arm_float_abi=softfp are set by default, actually, even arm_vervion=7 and use_neon=1 */
```

Here, the target is linux arm so this should be enough but if targetting android, it may be necessary to define the following variables

```
export ANDROID_SDK_VERSION=19
export GYP_DEFINES="$GYP_DEFINES  android_sdk_version=19"
```

NOTE 2 : the following exports are often reported on guides and tutorials. However, when used, they bring several problems (unrecognized -Xclang flag, etc.). It seems that they are no more usefull since gyp files automatically adjust those setup ! For me, avoiding them was the only way to get configuration and beginning of compilation work.

```
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
export AR=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar
export CC_host=gcc
export CXX_host=g++
```

Finally, configure the system before moving to the final compile step

```
cd ..
gclient runhooks --force
 cd trunk/
```

## Potential error 1 , Solved

The following error appears first :
=> gyp: Undefined variable android_ndk_root in chromium/src/third_party/openmax_dl/dl/dl.gyp
=> come back to previous section, you certainly forgot to define android_ndk_root variable in the enlighted file:
'android_ndk_root':'/trunk/third_party/android_tools/ndk/',
*/

## Potential error 2, solved

a relative link problem appears when trying to target trunk/build/linux/pkg-config-wrapper, you can get something similar to this :
Updating projects from gyp files...
/bin/sh: ../../../build/linux/pkg-config-wrapper: No such file or directory
gyp: Call to '../../../build/linux/pkg-config-wrapper "/media/workspace/lib/webrtc/trunk/arm-sysroot" "arm" --libs-only-L --libs-only-other nss' returned exit status 127. while loading dependencies of trunk/all.gyp while trying to load trunk/all.gyp
Error: Command /usr/bin/python trunk/build/gyp_chromium --depth=trunk trunk/all.gyp -Dextra_gyp_flag=0 returned non-zero exit status 1 in /media/workspace/lib/webrtc
=> if you want to solve this problem for all files having this error, look for wrong files with :

```
grep -Ir --exclude=\*.{c,h} "../../../build/linux/pkg-config-wrapper" *
```

and replace related relative path portion in pkg config line (at the beginning of each of the found files :
'pkg-config': 'trunk/build/linux/pkg-config-wrapper "<(sysroot)" "<(target_arch)"',

gclient runhooks --force

## final compile step

```
cd trunk
ninja -C out/Release/
ninja -C out/Debug/ // if required
```

an idea : sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-androideabi 
you should target third_party/android_tools/ndk/platforms/android-XXX/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/

// if having problems with clang, it can be desactivated with this additionnal option (rerun gclien runhooks after)

```
export GYP_DEFINES="$GYP_DEFINES clang=0"
```

Comment: Thanks. It working now! Now I'm trying to build for arm926ej-s (rev. 5) processor. Did you know - is it possible to build webrtc for armv5? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, i saw somewhere that arrmv6 was the old default config, now, default is armv7a (defauls values are arm_version=7 arm_use_neon=1  arm_fpu=vfpv3-d16 arm_float_abi=softfp). with armv6, floating point option will be "harder", arm_float_abi=hard, and vfpv3 should not be usable, neither neon). for armv5, it might be no longer supported, but you should check .good luck!

Comment: I just tried this, but cant' even get passed the initial WebRTC fetch... "gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
gclient sync --force" says "SVN cannot connect to the repository".  Prior to this I was following the instructions at "http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/development", but "fetch webrtc" fails a different way there (see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/Dt-GRIlLVe4).  I've walked through the software prerequisites several times, so as far as I can tell my host is up-to-date.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I got through it (thank you Google)...  I am behind a proxy, but I had set up the necessary stuff for git and svn; still it was failing.  See my post here for the solution that worked for me: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/Dt-GRIlLVe4