# cross compile WebRTC for ARM

Tags: linux, arm, webrtc, cross-compiling, chromium

I've tried to cross compile WebRTC for armv7 architecture (AllWinner A20).On www.webrtc.org there are no instructions how to do that, only for Android and IOS, on the internet I've found a few posts how to do that, here is it:

[WebRTC building for arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764171/webrtc-building-for-arm)

https://foxdogstudios.com/webrtc-on-linux

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/yzuk8wATMU8

https://github.com/mpromonet/webrtc-streamer/wiki/Cross-compile-WebRTC-for-Raspberry-Pi

All of them written around 2 years ago and starts with command:

**gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk**

As I understand it's old repository name and also buildsystem is changed for last 2 years. Can anybody help me with complete instruction how to build WebTRC for ARM?

Comment: Current build procedure is Installing chromium depot_tools and using `fetch`, `gclient` and `ninja` utilities (https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/). To cross-compile, I'd create an ARM chroot environment, because these tools from google (like`ninja`) are poorly documented, so I've got no idea how to configure them properly for a cross-compilation. Have you tried to build a straight i386/amd64 at least before searching for cross?

Comment: Its may be some late, but hopefully that tutorial will help you a lot. Visit Reference: [WebRtc_Library_Compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61322971/10413749)

Answer (score 3):

Not best solution to cross-compile WebRTC for ARM platform:

install depot tools and...

```
mkdir -p web_rtc && cd web_rtc
export GYP_DEFINES="OS=linux"
fetch --nohooks webrtc
gclient sync
cd src
./build/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-sysroot.py --arch=arm
gn gen out/Default --args='target_os="linux" target_cpu="arm"'

## UGLY HACK.
mv webrtc/modules/rtp_rtcp/test/testFec/test_packet_masks_metrics.cc webrtc/modules/rtp_rtcp/test/testFec/test_packet_masks_metrics.cc.bak
touch webrtc/modules/rtp_rtcp/test/testFec/test_packet_masks_metrics.cc

ninja -C out/Default
```

Comment: X11 is my problem now ... could you help me ?

arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Wl,--fatal-warnings -fPIC -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,defs -B../../third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--icf=all -pthread -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-rpath-link=../Release -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -o "./webrtc_tests" -Wl,--start-group @"./webrtc_tests.rsp"  -Wl,--end-group  -ldl -lrt -lm -lX11 -lXext -lXcomposite -lXrender -lXcursor -lXdamage -lXfixes -lXi -lXtst 
../../third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lX11

Comment: I used this:
gn gen ./out/Release --args='is_debug=false rtc_use_h264=false ffmpeg_branding="Chrome" rtc_include_tests=false is_clang=false target_cpu="arm" treat_warnings_as_errors=false rtc_enable_protobuf=false use_sysroot=false'

Comment: Did you ever figure the X11 linker errors out? I guess you just need to install a number of cross-compile libraries, but I also would like to know which. ;)

Comment: I have tried many solutions on the web, none of it working. With your simple solution I was finally able to build it. Thanks!

Comment: Could you pls tell me if there is certain .o file which is not getting included in built libwebrtc.a then what to do? I am simple doing gn gen out/Default --args='is_debug=false rtc_use_h264=true target_cpu="x64" target_os="linux" clang_use_chrome_plugins=false use_ghash=false symbol_level=2 use_custom_libcxx=false is_component_ffmpeg=true ffmpeg_branding="Chrome" rtc_include_tests=false rtc_build_examples=true rtc_build_tools=false use_rtti=true rtc_enable_protobuf=false rtc_use_h264=true rtc_link_pipewire=true proprietary_codecs=true' and `ninja -C . webrtc`

Answer (score 1):

## Create a python2 env using conda

`$ conda create -n yourenvname python=2.7`

## Create folder and enter it

`$ mkdir webrtc`
`$ cd webrtc`

## Clone depot tools

`$ git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git --depth 1`

## Add it to path

`$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/ME/webrtc/depot_tools/`

## Download source .... ALOT of time ans space

`$ fetch --nohooks webrtc`

`$ cd src`
`$ git clean -f`

#### Get the revision you want to compile

`$ git ls-remote https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc --heads branch-heads/72 80865776cf8a1a811166ee005951b7f5b01deacd    refs/branch-heads/72`
`$ gclient sync --force --revision 80865776cf8a1a811166ee005951b7f5b01deacd`

`$ ./install-build-deps.sh`
`$ gclient runhooks`

### COMPILE FOR X64

`$ gn gen out/x64_72 --args='is_debug=true  rtc_include_tests=false treat_warnings_as_errors=false use_rtti=true is_component_build=false  enable_iterator_debugging=false   is_clang=false use_sysroot=false linux_use_bundled_binutils=false use_custom_libcxx=false use_custom_libcxx_for_host=false target_os="linux"  target_cpu="x64"'`        
`$ cd ./out/x64_72`
`$ ninja -C . -j 8`

### COMPILE FORE ARM64

`$ python build/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-sysroot.py --arch=arm64`

`$ gn gen out/arm64_72 --args='is_debug=false  enable_iterator_debugging=false   treat_warnings_as_errors=false rtc_include_tests=false target_os="linux"  target_cpu="arm64" is_clang=true  '` 
`$ cd ./out/arm64_72`
`$ ninja -C . -j 8`

### Good luck