# Error while building WebRTC for android on Ubuntu

Tags: python, android, webrtc, webrtc-android

I am trying to build WebRTC for Android on Ubuntu 16.04. I have followed the steps mentioned at:
https://medium.com/@abdularis/how-to-compile-native-webrtc-from-source-for-android-d0bac8e4c933 ( I found similar steps in the other links also)

I checked out the version: **branch-heads/m79**

I am getting the following error while building the code with the command:
`python tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py`

```
ERROR at //build/config/android/internal_rules.gni:3051:7: Assertion failed.
      assert(_is_annotation_processor || _is_java_binary || _has_sources)
      ^-----
See //build/config/android/rules.gni:1489:5: whence it was called.
    java_library_impl(target_name) {
    ^-------------------------------
See //build/config/android/rules.gni:1844:5: whence it was called.
    java_library(target_name) {
    ^--------------------------
See //webrtc.gni:850:5: whence it was called.
    android_library(target_name) {
    ^-----------------------------
See //rtc_base/BUILD.gn:1359:3: whence it was called.
  rtc_android_library("base_java") {
  ^---------------------------------
See //BUILD.gn:423:7: which caused the file to be included.
      "rtc_base",
      ^---------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_aar.py", line 234, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "build_aar.py", line 230, in main
    args.build_dir, args.extra_gn_switches, args.extra_ninja_switches)
  File "build_aar.py", line 210, in BuildAar
    extra_ninja_switches)
  File "build_aar.py", line 166, in Build
    _RunGN(gn_args_list)
  File "build_aar.py", line 93, in _RunGN
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '/home/architsinha/work/WebRTC_Android/src/third_party/depot_tools/gn.py', 'gen', '/tmp/tmpuxZSnM/armeabi-v7a', '--args=arm_version=7 use_goma=false target_cpu="arm" is_component_build=false is_debug=false rtc_include_tests=false target_os="android"']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

If I try the other method by running the command
`gn gen out/Debug --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm"'`
 I get the following error:

```
ERROR at //BUILD.gn:648:20: Assignment had no effect.
      java_files = [
                   ^
You set the variable "java_files" here and it was unused before it went
out of scope.
See //BUILD.gn:647:5: whence it was called.
    junit_binary("android_junit_tests") {
    ^------------------------------------
```

How can I fix this error? Is there some step which I have missed?

Comment: I've had a similar problem, running 'gclient sync' and letting it complete (took me about 50 minutes and a few attempts) solved this error. However I now have a different error so if you get this far please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck with the same issues. While working on the following commands make sure you're using the same(`only-1`) tab of *Linux terminal* for WebRTC Native Development.

> Please visit this article which is quite helpful for webrtc native
> development as well as the compilation of webrtc native stack: [Compilation of WebRtc Library for Android](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Compile_WebRTC_Library_For_Android)

First of all, make sure of the following things that you have already installed, if not then use these commands to do that:

```
 - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
 - sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
 - sudo apt-get install pkg-config
 - sudo apt-get update
```

---

After that, start the following steps one by one. Every step takes its own time based on the *machine specs* and *internet speed*, so make sure every step is completed without interruption.

```
1- git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git

2- export PATH="$PATH:${HOME}/depot_tools"

3- mkdir webrtc_android

3.1- cd webrtc_android

4- fetch --nohooks webrtc_android
    
5- gclient sync

6- cd src/

7- ./build/install-build-deps.sh

8- git branch -r

9- git checkout origin/master

# To check you're in origin/master branch
10- git branch

11- tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py
```

---

It turns out that you will end up with the compilation and building of `libwebrtc.aar` in the `webrtc_android/src/` directory.

Now, If you have already completed your task to `step-7` with the `branch-heads/m79`, then
select the `branch` of `origin/master` instead of `m79`. To do that try the following steps:

Make sure you're in this directory `webrtc_android/src/`:

```
 - git checkout origin/master
 # To make sure you're using origin/master
 - git branch
 - gclient revert
 - gclient sync
 - tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py
```

And hopefully, you will have your issues sorted. Currently, You are checking out a branch that is behind the `origin/master` and doesn't have all dependencies and modules over there which are necessary to build your `libwebrtc.aar`.

---

Now, if you tried these both procedures to build the WebRTC such as:

1- Using AAR Build Tools (`./tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py`)

2- Using Manual Compilation (`gn gen out/Debug --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm"'`)

2.1- Compiling (`ninja -C out/Debug`)

Both procedures will work.

---

Comment: Please visit this article which is quite helpful for webrtc native development as well as compilation of webrtc native stack. [compilation_of_webRtc_Library](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Compile_WebRTC_Library_For_Android)

Answer (score 0):

It can take a few attempts but running `gclient sync` a few times worked for me.

It can take a very long time to get all of the files and if it is interrupted it won't retrieve them.